# MySQL SSL Master-Slave replication not syncing

Tags: mysql, ssl, replication

I have originally posted this thread on stackoverflow and after a comment I moved it here. [The original post can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972254/mysql-ssl-master-slave-replication-not-syncing?noredirect=1#comment31528036_20972254)

I have setup a typical Master-Slave replication scheme for my MySQL database. Up until now the topology is consisted from only one master and one slave node, both are using SSL to securely communicate with each other.

On Master node:

[image]

On the Slave node:

[image]

I have no error in the error.log on neither side, but when I change something on the Master node and then check the slave, the change is not replicated.

I followed this tutorial so I am pretty confident that my my.cnf are properly configured.

Is there any hints on what can be wrong in this setup?

Comment: You've mis configured your slave. Please check the replication filters;

Replicate_Do_DB: /var/lib/mysql/live01 ...

Comment: @eroomydna I have fixed that thank you for pointing it out, but the changes are still not propagated from master to slave.

Comment: What actions did you take, how is the SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G output looking now?

Comment: @eroomydna It only contains /var/lib/mysql/live01

Comment: This is a filesystem path. Try only using only  
live01 
as your argument.

Comment: @eroomydna I have changed it to simply live01, I can see that the connection is established without any problem and that the SLAVE_IO_State is saying that it is waiting for events from the master, but when I change something on the master the change is nowhere to be found on the slave.
I have read that there might be an issue with non deterministic functions like UUID. All my primary keys are generated with UUID is that something that could cause this issue? 
thank you for your support.

Comment: If you can create a live01.test table, the DDL should replicate and wouldn't be prone to any non-deterministic issues. You should use mysqlbinlog to parse the binary log (even check the mtime on the file) to ensure that your event was written there and then review the state of the slave. Feel free to post more output from your tests. SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G, SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS etc.